# mysql if else for selecting correct query

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I want to execute two different mysql queries with a given parameter value.

This is my query:

```
select Gender, count(EmployeeId) as NoOfEmployees 
from people_HR.PEOPLE_HR
where EmploymentType = 'INTERNSHIP' and ((StartDate < '2006-07-01' AND EmployeeStatus = 'Active') OR (EmployeeStatus = 'Left' AND '2006-07-01' <= FinalDayofEmployment AND StartDate < '2006-07-01' )) and Gender<>'' group by Gender
```

This employment type and dates will be assign as parameters. I need to run query for whole table if EmploymentType = 'Total'. How can I achieve this through mysql query?

Note: Below code as a pseudo code which I need to implement.

```
if (EmploymentType = 'Total') 
select Gender, count(EmployeeId) as NoOfEmployees 
from people_HR.PEOPLE_HR
where ((StartDate < '2006-07-01' AND EmployeeStatus = 'Active') OR (EmployeeStatus = 'Left' AND '2006-07-01' <= FinalDayofEmployment AND StartDate < '2006-07-01' )) and Gender<>'' group by Gender

else
select Gender, count(EmployeeId) as NoOfEmployees 
from people_HR.PEOPLE_HR
where EmploymentType = 'INTERNSHIP' and ((StartDate < '2006-07-01' AND EmployeeStatus = 'Active') OR (EmployeeStatus = 'Left' AND '2006-07-01' <= FinalDayofEmployment AND StartDate < '2006-07-01' )) and Gender<>''group by Gender
```

Any help on this highly appreciated.

Note: This is not a stored procedure. Therefore can't use direct "IF" and I need to implement through "select if".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) statement for this scenario.This will work on SQL queries.

```
    select Gender, count(EmployeeId) as NoOfEmployees 
    from people_HR.PEOPLE_HR
    where
    CASE WHEN @EmploymentType = 'TOTAL' THEN 
    EmploymentType<>''
    ELSE 
    EmploymentType=@EmploymentType
    END 
    and ((StartDate < '2006-07-01' AND EmployeeStatus = 'Active') OR (EmployeeStatus = 'Left' AND '2006-07-01' <= FinalDayofEmployment AND StartDate < '2006-07-01' )) and Gender<>''group by Gender
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    IF (@EmploymentType = 'Total') THEN

           select Gender, count(EmployeeId) as NoOfEmployees 
           from people_HR.PEOPLE_HR
           where ((StartDate < '2006-07-01' AND EmployeeStatus = 'Active') OR (EmployeeStatus = 'Left' AND '2006-07-01' <= FinalDayofEmployment AND StartDate < '2006-07-01' )) and Gender<>'' group by Gender


     ELSE

          select Gender, count(EmployeeId) as NoOfEmployees 
          from people_HR.PEOPLE_HR
          where EmploymentType = 'INTERNSHIP' and ((StartDate < '2006-07-01' AND EmployeeStatus = 'Active') OR (EmployeeStatus = 'Left' AND '2006-07-01' <= FinalDayofEmployment AND StartDate < '2006-07-01' )) and Gender<>''group by Gender

    END IF
```

By the way you can only use if statement in a stored procedure or a function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my one is not a stored procedure. I need to use it in direct mysql query

Comment: Well, this does answer the question that was asked. So I think you should accept it. If however you are not using a stored procedure, it's a lot easier to implement this with an if else in your application rather than in the query.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF (@EmploymentType = 'Total')
BEGIN
   select Gender, count(EmployeeId) as NoOfEmployees 
   from people_HR.PEOPLE_HR
   where ((StartDate < '2006-07-01' AND EmployeeStatus = 'Active') OR (EmployeeStatus = 'Left' AND '2006-07-01' <= FinalDayofEmployment AND StartDate < '2006-07-01' )) and Gender<>'' group by Gender
END

ELSE
BEGIN
  select Gender, count(EmployeeId) as NoOfEmployees 
  from people_HR.PEOPLE_HR
  where EmploymentType = 'INTERNSHIP' and ((StartDate < '2006-07-01' AND EmployeeStatus = 'Active') OR (EmployeeStatus = 'Left' AND '2006-07-01' <= FinalDayofEmployment AND StartDate < '2006-07-01' )) and Gender<>''group by Gender
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this only works with stored procedures. No luck in my case